# Working time not calculating correctly in tasks

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I am using MS Project 2016.  I am working on a large project working 10 hour days 6 days per week.  I have adjusted working times and days and set Sunday to a non working day.  But the finish dates are still including Sunday - how do I fix this?  Any help appreciated please

Comment: If you double click the task and go to the advance tab of the dialog, does it shows the same calendar for the task?

Comment: Yes it does, I have checked all tasks and are they are in the same calendar

Answer (score 1):

Have you dragged the task to the date you want ? Just drag it and adjust it